# Executar const ao abrir um app

Tags: javascript, react-native

eu estou fazendo uma ToDoList e queria que ela se organizasse assim que eu abrir ela, mas eu não consigo executar a função sem coloca-la em um botão.

segue a função:

```
const handleOrganize = () => {
    let newList =[...list]

    newList.sort((a,b) =>{
      if(a.task > b.task){
        console.log('+1')
        return 1;
        
      } else{
        if(b.task > a.task){
          console.log('-1')
          return -1;
        }else{
          console.log('-1')
          return 0;
        }
      }
    });
    setTask(newList)
  }
```

consigo executala atravez desse botão:

```
<AnimatedBtn style={styles.fab}
  useNativeDriver
  animation="bounceInUp"
  duration={1500}
  onPress={(handleOrganize)}
  >
    <Ionicons name="ios-add" size={35} color="#FFF"/>
  </AnimatedBtn>
```

queria saber como eu posso chamar aquela função assim que eu abrir o app.

codigo completo:

```
import React, { useState, useCallback, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View,Text, SafeAreaView, StatusBar, TouchableOpacity, FlatList, Modal, TextInput} from 'react-native';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons'
import styles from './assets/styles/style';
import TaskList from './src/components/TaskList';
import * as Animatable from 'react-native-animatable'
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import { LinearGradient } from 'expo-linear-gradient'

const AnimatedBtn = Animatable.createAnimatableComponent(TouchableOpacity);

export default function app(){

  const [task,setTask]= useState([]) 
  const [list,setList]=useState(null)
  const [open,setOpen] =useState(false);
  const [input,setInput] = useState('')
  const [impor,setImpor] = useState('')

//Buscando tarefas quando abre o app
  useEffect(()=>{

    async function loadTask(){
      const taskStorage = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@task')

      if(taskStorage){
        setTask(JSON.parse(taskStorage))
      }
    }

    loadTask();
  },[]);


  //Salvando caso tenha alguma tarefa alterada
  useEffect(()=>{

    async function saveTask(){
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('@task',JSON.stringify(task))
      setList(task)
    }
    


    saveTask();
    
  },[task]);


  function handleAdd(){

    if(input === '') return;

    const data={
      key:input,
      task:input,
      importance:impor,
    }

    setTask([...task,data])
    setOpen(false)
    setInput('')
    setImpor('')

  }

  const handleDelete = useCallback((data)=>{
    const find = task.filter(r=>r.key !== data.key)
    setTask(find)
  })

  
    
  


    const handleOrganize = () => {
    let newList =[...list]
    console.log('iniciou')

    newList.sort((a,b) =>{
      if(a.task > b.task){
        console.log('+1')
        return 1;
        
      } else{
        if(b.task > a.task){
          console.log('-1')
          return -1;
        }else{
          console.log('-1')
          return 0;
        }
      }
    });
    setTask(newList)
  }
  

  useEffect(handleOrganize, [task]);

  return(
    
    <LinearGradient
        colors={['#4C0B62', '#111820']}
        style={{flex: 1}}
      >
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <StatusBar backgroundColor="#4C0B62" barStyle="light-content"/>
      <View>
        <Text style={styles.title}> Minhas Tarefas </Text>
      </View>
      

      <FlatList
      marginHorizontal={10}
      showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
      data={list}
      keyExtractor={(item) => String(item.key)}
      renderItem={( {item} ) => <TaskList data={item}  handleDelete={handleDelete}/>}
      />
      
      <Modal animationType="slide" transparent={false} visible={open}>
      <LinearGradient
        colors={['#260431', '#1C0324']}
        style={{flex: 1}}
      >
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.modal}>
          <View style={styles.modalHeader}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> setOpen(false)}>
              <Ionicons style={{marginLeft:5,marginRight:5}}name="md-arrow-back" size={30} color="#FFF"/>
            </TouchableOpacity>

            <Text style={styles.modalTitle}>Nova Tarefa</Text>
            
          </View>

          <Animatable.View style={styles.modalBody} animation="fadeInUp" useNativeDriver>
            <TextInput
            multiline={true}
            placeholderTextColor="#747474"
            autoCorrect={false}
            placeholder="O que tem pra fazer ?"
            style={styles.input}
            value={input}
            onChangeText={(texto)=>setInput(texto)}
            />

            <TextInput
            multiline={true}
            placeholderTextColor="#747474"
            autoCorrect={false}
            placeholder="O que tem pra fazer ?"
            style={styles.input}
            value={impor}
            onChangeText={(texto)=>setImpor(texto)}
            />


          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.handleAdd} onPress={ handleAdd}>
            <Text style={styles.handleAddText}>Cadastrar</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </Animatable.View>
        </SafeAreaView>
        </LinearGradient>

        
      </Modal>


      <AnimatedBtn style={styles.fab}
      useNativeDriver
      animation="bounceInUp"
      duration={1500}
      onPress={()=>setOpen(true)}
      >
        <Ionicons name="ios-add" size={35} color="#FFF"/>
      </AnimatedBtn>
    </SafeAreaView>

    </LinearGradient>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O que você precisa é o hook `useEffect`, que executa uma função na primeira vez que o componente renderiza e após cada renderização subsequente em que uma de suas dependências é alterada. No seu caso, você quer que a lista seja ordenada na primeira renderização e sempre que a lista mudar, logo, o seu código deve ficar assim

```js
useEffect(handleOrganize, [list]);
```

Basta adicionar essa linha em qualquer ponto da definição da função do seu componente.

**NOTA**: Essa solução não funciona com componentes em classe.

Comment: Eu ja havia tentado usar essa linha de codigo, mas quando coloco e inicio o app novamente aponta o seguinte erro: " TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'iter[Symbol.iterator]') "

Comment: Provavelmente tem a ver com essa variável `list` que eu suponho que você está inicializando como `null`. Esse erro acontece porque você está usando o operador `...`, que tenta iterar sobre um objeto. Como `list` é `null`, o Javascript não consegue fazer isso. Mas tudo isso são suposições... Se você puder colocar o código completo, dá pra te ajudar melhor...

Comment: adicionei o codigo completo na pergunta, se puder dar uma conferida.